# Selecting AnnotationView twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I am working on a simple application which shows map with some pins i customized. Whenever i click to my custom pin, i am pushing `detailedMapViewController` to see `annotationView`.

Everything is working fine except if i want to click the same pin again after returning back to the root controller. If i choose another pin that i didn't before, everything still works good. But whenever i click my last pin nothing happens.

Here is my method for clicking the custom pin i've created.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    DetailedMapViewController *detailedMapViewController = [[DetailedMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedMapViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailedMapViewController.pointAnnotation = view.annotation;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedMapViewController animated:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [detailedMapViewController release];
}
```

I put breakpoint for the method and when i click the pin again i can't even reach to the breakpoint. Something is preventing me to call that method again. Maybe i need to return somewhere back. Anyways a little help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide your code of adding annotations to map also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your method to something like this

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
 {
  DetailedMapViewController *detailedMapViewController = [[DetailedMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedMapViewController" bundle:nil];

  detailedMapViewController.pointAnnotation = view.annotation;

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedMapViewController animated:YES];
 [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
 [detailedMapViewController release];

 //New line
   [_mapView deselectAnnotation:[view annotation] animated:NO]
}
```